# How to correctly get custom emoji on Discord.JS?

Tags: javascript, emoji, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get my Discord.JS bot to display custom emojis. What I currently have to turn the emojis into Strings is:

```
const bo = client.emojis.get("name", "BO").toString;
```

But it fails because bo is undefined and therefore cannot be a String. One of the emojis in the Discord chat I want to add it to is triggered by :BO:, so I'm confused about why it isn't working.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get` method is from [Map's get method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) since Collection extends Map.
The usage would be `get(keyValue)`, which in this case, `client.emojis` return a `Collection<Snowflake, Emoji>`, and the `key` in this case would be `Snowflake`.

Hence, you can simply get the emoji's ID (`id` property for emoji exists) and do `client.emojis.get(id)`, or simply make a loop through the collection of the `emoji` value, and find matching emoji names based on `emoji.name` property.